# Syntax Highlighting with Fine Granularity

Tags: vim

Is there a way to assign an individual character, as identified by a height and depth index, to a highlight group? Every match feature I have come across uses a regex pattern as input.

The reason I ask is because I am making a syntax coloring plugin that will make text an increasingly lighter shade of gray with increasing parenthesis depth. If vim has no such feature and another algorithm makes character-by-character highlighting unnecessary, please point me to it!

Comment: You can use `\%10l` and `\%10c` to match line 10 and column 10 respectively in a regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

Vim has a whole set of special regular expression atoms that can specify buffer positions.

For lines, `\%23l` matches only in line 23. You can also use `\%>23l` for all lines starting from 23, and concatenate two of those with `<` and `>` to specify ranges.

For columns, there are the corresponding `\%23c` and `\%23v`. The former uses *byte indices* (what Vim somewhat confusingly calls "columns"), as returned by functions like `col()` and `getpos()`, the latter screen widths (from `virtcol()`).

By combining those atoms, you can select arbitrary blocks of text, and highlight them, e.g. with `:call matchadd(...)`. See `:help /\%l` for details on the atoms.

---

For your plugin implementation, you may be able to get some ideas from the [vim js context coloring plugin](https://github.com/bigfish/vim-js-context-coloring), which highlights JavaScript code according to its scope.